# Converting from hexadecimal to binary values

Tags: python-2.7, binary, hex, type-conversion

Am converting a value from hexadecimal to binary value.I used bin() of python like this:

```
value = 05808080
print bin(int(value, 16))

output i got is 0b101100000001000000010000000(output should be 32 bit)
output should be 0000 0101 1000 0000 1000 0000 1000 0000(correct output)
```

What is this 'b' in the output and how can i replace it with correct binary values.I think two values up here is almost same except issue with "b" in output.How will i resolve this ?

Comment: Is value a string? If I enter it as an int, without `'`, I get SyntaxError, because an octal number (starting with `0` can not contain an 8.

Comment: "TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output you get is correct, it just needs to be formatted a bit. The leading `0b` indicates that it is a binary number, similarly to how `0x` stands for hexadecimal and `0` for octal.

First, slice away the `0b` with `[2:]` and use `zfill` to add leading zeros:

```
>>> value = '05808080'
>>> b = bin(int(value, 16))
>>> b[2:]
'101100000001000000010000000'
>>> b[2:].zfill(32)
'00000101100000001000000010000000'
```

Finally, split the string in intervals of four characters and join those with spaces:

```
>>> s = b[2:].zfill(32)
>>> ' '.join(s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, 32, 4))
'0000 0101 1000 0000 1000 0000 1000 0000'
```

If you can live without those separator spaces, you can also use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> '{:032b}'.format(int(value, 16))
'00000101100000001000000010000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def hex2bin(HexInputStr, outFormat=4):
    '''This function accepts the following two args.
    1) A Hex number as input string and
    2) Optional int value that selects the desired Output format(int value 8 for byte and 4 for nibble [default])
    The function returns binary equivalent value on the first arg.'''
    int_value = int(HexInputStr, 16)
    if(outFormat == 8):
        output_length = 8 * ((len(HexInputStr) + 1 ) // 2) # Byte length output i.e input A is printed as 00001010
    else:
        output_length = (len(HexInputStr)) * 4 # Nibble length output i.e input A is printed as 1010


    bin_value = f'{int_value:0{output_length}b}' # new style
    return bin_value

print(hex2bin('3Fa', 8)) # prints 0000001111111010
```